# Changing variable initialization values with user input

Tags: java, initialization, save

Lets say we have a java class with a static integer variable initialized to zero, example shown below:

```
public final Example {
   public static final int integer = 0;
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Have the user enter a value for the variable (lets say 5 for this example)
- Change the source code itself so that the variable is now assigned the value the user has entered AND is initialized to that value the next time the program is run, like so:

`public final Example {
   public static final int integer = 5;
}`

What I'd like to know is:

- is it possible to change source code like that?
- if yes, how would I go about doing it?

the intention is to use the Example class to store and save a specific number of variables, with the user able to change what those variables are initialized to from the GUI. Changed initialization values MUST be saved for when the program is run again.

I understand there are ways to store and save values other than using a class file, but I would like to use this method, if possible, because I feel it would be best for the specific project I am working on.

thanks for any help, guys!

Comment: Yes it is possible. No you should not do it. Save this in a file or using the Java preferences API like any sane person would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java way to store and retrieve preferences in a persistent way is like this. First, get a `Preferences` instance, and pass in the class that you want to be associated with this set of preferences (use whatever is the main class for your application unless you want different sets of preferences for different parts of the application):

```
private Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainWindow.class);
```

Now to retrieve a `String`-based value with a key of `someValue`, you would need

```
String someValue = prefs.get("someValue", null);
```

The `null` on the end is the default value: it's what you'll get back if there's nothing stored with that key. You don't have to have the default as `null`, of course.

To store, you'd do

```
prefs.put("someValue", valueToStore);
```

This will do it in a nice platform-independent way, and store it in the appropriate place for whatever system you're running on.

There's also a `.putInt()` and `.getInt()`, etc., for storing other types. It looks as though the `int` ones are what you're most likely to need here, but you should be aware of all of them.

---

But in answer to your specific question, you absolutely can't (read: shouldn't) have user input automatically altering the source code that gets run next time! Store the preferences using the `Preferences` object, not by changing the source code.

This isn't pedantry. Doing it by altering the source code would be

1. more fragile;
2. dangerous;
3. harder to code;
4. less maintainable;
5. more long-winded;
6. less portable.

This list is not exhaustive :)